# Preloading font menu

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am writing an application that has a customization dialog box that contains a NSPopupButton that displays all of the available fonts using attributed strings so as to display the font name in the actual font.

Because I anticipate the dialog box only being opened a fraction of the times the application is run, it is in its on xib file and only loaded when needed.

My "problem" is that the first time (only) when the user clicks on the font button, there is 1 5-10 second lag (with spinning beach ball).  I assume this because it must render the underlying menu.  I am loading the fonts from FSFontManager during the dialog box's awakeFromNib, but that apparently is insufficient.

Before I chase down a bunch of dead ends trying to figure out how to get the menu to "pre-render," does anyone have some suggestions of what my smartest line of attack might be?   (Preferably in a separate thread???)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to share the solution I ended up going with.

In the app delegate's awakeFromNib, I spawned a new thread that did nothing but create an unattached NNTextField, loop overall fonts updating the content of the text field with an attributed string using that font, and then close itself.

Now, unless I am really quick in getting to the font menu that was lagging, it pops up with no lag.

I created a "free floating" NSTextField in MainMenu.xib (i.e. it was NOT part of any window) and connected it to an IBOutlet in the app delegate.

The following is from my app delegate's implementation:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
  // irrelevant stuff deleted...

  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(preloadFonts) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

-(void)preloadFonts
{
  NSTextField *tf = [[NSTextField alloc]init];
  NSArray *fonts = [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] availableFontFamilies];
  [fonts enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *name=obj;
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSFont fontWithName:name size:12.]
                                                           forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:name attributes:attributes];
    [tf setAttributedStringValue:str];
  }];
}
```